# Is it legal to read data out of a function pointer?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Per the standard, is it legal to access data from a function pointer?

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(){
    //
}

int main() {
    int (*fp)(void) = &test;

    int i=0;
    for(i; i<10; ++i)
        printf("%x", *(fp+i));
}
```

[Running on ideone](https://ideone.com/6t3mBm), it seems to work - but I'm wondering if it is expected to, or whether it is implementation-defined, and the page may be read-protected by OS?

Comment: It will not work on Harvard-architecture processors, which have separate address spaces for code and data. On x86 I'd much prefer if you'd cast that pointer to `char*`, since functions are not objects and have no size; You're relying on GCC's extension that defines pointer arithmetic on `void*` or function pointers as byte increments. As for page protection, not a concern: Logically, code _must_ be readable to be executable (else, how would you know what to run?).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I was under the impression exec- was distinct from read-protection -- not the case?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist a CPU could be granted access to read some portion of memory only on the Fetch stage and not on the Execute stage of the instruction processing. There's a patent [here](http://www.google.tl/patents/US20140281137) about execute-only protection; I haven't read it in detail but I guess it's possible

Comment: It is; Typically in an executable you've got read-only data sections (`.rodata`, `r--`), read-write data sections (`.data`, `rw-`) and executable code (`.text`, `r-x`).

Comment: @Diego That's interesting, but how perverse! It smells like it encourages security through obscurity of the machine code.

Comment: Interesting, thank you both. If it's the subject of a modern patent then certainly my answer is 'execute -> read', but that it's not really up to C standard to say. What would happen on a Harvard arch then - it'd just be either out of addressable space, or some data bytes? Or would the Harvard-target compiler catch it?

Comment: @OllieFord To "ping" somebody for attention, just use their name prefixed with an @ , it will land a notification in my inbox. A Harvard architecture processor, because it uses different address spaces for code & data (and potentially different pointer formats and even sizes), could do many things. For instance it could be the case, given `void foo(void){}` and `int bar = 0;`, that `(void*)&foo == (void*)&bar` – even though they're not at the same location, they have the same address. So you'd try accessing *program* memory at address A, but you'd actually access *data* memory instead at A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C standards perspective, no, it's not.

Annex J in N1570 has a chapter on common extensions:

> ### J.5 Common extensions
>
> 1. The following extensions are widely used in many systems, but are not portable to all
>      implementations. The inclusion of any extension that may cause a strictly conforming
>      program to become invalid renders an implementation nonconforming. ...

And then mentions this extension later in J.5.7 Function pointer casts:

> 2. A pointer to a function may be cast to a pointer to an object or to **void**, allowing a
>      function to be inspected or modified (for example, by a debugger) (6.5.4).

Comment: Accepted this as it answers the question as I asked it - but I'd suggest the interested reader see [Iwillnotexist's comments on OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157987/is-it-legal-to-read-data-out-of-a-function-pointer/30162199#comment48423164_30157987) for more on why.

Answer (score -2):

Function pointers are legal by design.

Manipulating pointers yourself is also legal by design, BUT can cause undefined behaviour, including crashing your program.

I tried expanding the loop to 10000 and got a runtime error, propably because memory access was prohibited there.

Comment: `*(fp+i)` looks like a dereference to me

Comment: I'm not sure about "manipulating pointers .. causes UB", think that's surely missing a qualifier?

Comment: Manipulating pointers does not necessarily cause undefined behavior -- the statement is too general